# how to parse pst file with tika into a list of emails, instead of a string of emails

Tags: python, email, apache-tika, pst

I am using tika as a command line utility to parse a pst file:

```
java -jar tika-app.jar -t my_emails.pst
```

The output is a string of the contents of all the emails. This makes it hard to separate each email. Is it possible to output as a list of emails, e.g. output as a python list of dictionaries, where each email is a dictionary [{email_1_key: email_1_value}, {email_2_key: email_2_value}]?

I also tried using tika-python, but it does not do this too.

Comment: Please also include what the current output string from tika looks like.